# Cloudbees Jenkins dashboard customization

Tags: jenkins, dashboard, cloudbees

I would like to know how to customize dashboard on Jenkins under Cloudbees.
In the build execution I'm generating different reports (PMD, Cobertura, etc) but I don't know how to add/publish these reports in the dashboard.

Looking on Jenkins Wiki I've found [this topic](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Dashboard+View). It says:

> On the create new view page, give your view a name and select the Dashboard type

The problem is that there isn't any "Dashboard type" and only the following options are available:

- Groovy Script View
- List View
- My View

and none of these options allows to add reports.

Answer (score 0):

"Free" and "Base" cloud plans provides only the essenstial jenkins plugins. Please 
Refer: https://grandcentral.cloudbees.com/services/plans/dev.

Comment: Yes, I know. I'm using only "essential plugins" presents in the free plan. The plugins I'm using are generating reports. The problem I'm facing is that the reports are not published!

Answer (score 0):

Try a "List view" instead. You can make this the default view under using the /configure page.